# What are the best practices in building a winform application?

Tags: .net, winforms, design-patterns

i'm about to start a new project using visual studio and Windows Form and i'm wondering what are the first things to do, even before start programming. This is my first project and i'm still new to .NET.

So far i only choose a good architecture pattern such as Model-View-Presenter. But now i'm facing the following problem:

1) The application will use some third-party dll so i need to provide them with the installer.

2) The application should run on 32/64 bit OS and for windows 7/8/10.

3) It should be multi-language

The question is, generally speaking, what are you experiences organizing an app like this, if any.

Any external link to some open source project structure would be helpfull. I know this is a quite general question but i only need a starting point.

Thank you for your time

V.

Answer (score 4):

1) The application will use some third-party dll so i need to provide them with the installer.

- With ClickOnce Publishing you will be able to deploy a self installing app capable of automatic updating.

2) The application should run on 32/64 bit OS and for windows 7/8/10.

- Don't mind, it will run on both systems in most of cases.

3) It should be multi-language

- If you put all strings in a .resx file (Project Properties > Resources) then you can create culture specific files (e.g. Resources.it-IT.resx) and the system will use the file based on the thread culture.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding MVP for Windows Forms, I'd urge you to tread carefully. It's a pattern that can become very messy, very quickly if your application has any degree of complexity.

I spent a lot of time finding what I considered to be 'best practise' when using this pattern with Windows Forms. I began to crystallise my efforts in a framework that's available [here](https://github.com/davidmosborne/NTangled), along with some samples to illustrate my thinking. Feel free to take a look and give some feedback or enhance as you see fit.